# How should I proceed relating to factory usages for testing purposes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9, RSpect 2 and FactoryGirl. I would like to know how I should  proceed in my case relating to factory usages for testing purposes.

I have seeded the database (by using the `/db/seed.rb` file) with some data that is necessary in order to initialize a make my application to work. Now I am in trouble because I implemented\created some factories and when I instantiate them (eg: `Factory(:user)`, `Factory(:user_authorization)`, ...) those are "combined" with the seeded data present in the database.

So, the question is: **should I use factories *exclusively*** (that is, to use only factory data by not considering the test database data) **or can I use those in "combination" with the seeded data in the database?** That is, should I consider also database seeded data or I should implement\emulate all seeded data with factories?

Comment: I do not quite understand why your factories would not work after seeding the database. Could you please show a specific example of a factory, the usage and the error you would get? We seed the database as well, of course, and use factories all the time when testing.

Comment: @nathanvda - I do not mean (I never wrote) that my factories do not work. I just would like to know some approach to use at the same time both factories and seeded data and mostly if it is a good approach.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood your question. I thought you had a specific problem by the combined use of both factories and seeds, I thought it was a practical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my projects I use seeding for the data my application really needs to get started. E.g. the first user (admin), domain tables, ... For these I do not use factories.

Secondly I use factories during testing to simulate any data that should be present.

In my opinion those co-exist perfectly. I use the factories when the contents of the data is actually not that important (there has to be some user, some post, some comment ...), but with the seeding the actual data in the database is very important, and if I would be using factories for that, I would be redefining every attribute anyway, so for me there would be no benefit of using a factory.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use factory_girl within in seed.rb.  This post explains it a little more.  http://xtargets.com/2011/02/06/seeding-your-rails-db-with-factory-girl/

Comment: Is the linked post approach a little bit "strange"\"dangerous"? However, I would like to know a common approach to use factories and seeded data... I think I am not the only person who has had this trouble.

Comment: Yes, imho the example from the linked post is something I would only do in the preparation of a test. Not in a seed. A seed in my opinion is data that is needed to make your app work (bootstrapping). E.g. the first user, domain tables, ... but not random data. But the post does show it is possible.